# Return table column value on row click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table and I want the user to be able to click on a row of the table and have an alert pop up with a certain column value.  I've been able to get the alert to work with returning the first column value in the selected row, but can't figure out how to get any other column information.

My javascript code looks like this so far:

```
$("#pass_table tr").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
    });

$('.ok').on('click', function(e){
  if($("#pass_table tr.selected td:first").html()){
    var retval = confirm("Continue using: "+$("#pass_table tr.selected td:first").html()+"?");
    if(retval == true){
      alert("it worked!")
    } else {
      alert("you canceled!!")
    }
  } else {
    alert("You must select a row.")
  }
});
```

and my html code looks like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  {{ pass_table | safe }}
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="text-center">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary ok" value="Generate File"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

where `pass_table` is generated from a generic pandas dataframe (`df`) using `DataFrame.to_html()` like this:

```
html_table = re.sub(' pass_table', '" id="pass_table', df.to_html(classes='pass_table'))
```

How would I go about displaying info from column 13 of the selected row in my table?

Comment: Instead of using `td:first` use a `nth-child()` selector. https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: @KassymDorsel I tried using `var colinfo = $("#pass_table tr.selected tr:nth-child(13)").html();` to get info from column 13 of the selected row but it returned `undefined`.  Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: You'll want to do `$("#pass_table tr.selected td:nth-child(13)").html()`. Note it's `td` not `tr`.

Comment: @KassymDorsel that worked! Thanks!  If you want to put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are using the `:first` css selector which gives you only the first column. You'll want to use the `:nth-child()` selector instead.

`$("#pass_table tr.selected td:nth-child(13)").html()`

See here: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

*You can access the clicked element by the jQuery events target-property* or easier `$(this)`

Any information about the clicked element you can get as usually

```
$(document).on('click', '.pass_table td', function(event){
      //zero-based colNo and rowNo
       var $col = $(this); // or $(event.target)
       var $row = $col.parents('tr:first').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
       var content = $col.text();
       var colNo = $col.prevAll().size();
       var rowNo = $row.prevAll().size();
       alert('content: ' + content + '; rowNo: ' + rowNo + ';colNo' + colNo);
    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrcvdcc7/4/) with a showcase

Comment: The problem is that the user selects the row and then clicks a button to submit (which brings up the alert).  So the event in my case is actually the button click rather than the row selected.

Comment: then store the values you retrieved on click of cell. E.g store the value by a call of jQuery's data like $('.ok').data('$col', $col)  (inside of table-clicklistener) and use $('.ok').data('$col') inside click handler of button to retrieve the last clicked cell